# POST request, not sending anything, isset($_POST) always false

Tags: c#, php, json, post

I am new to C#. I tried all solutions to other questions and still i can't find what is wrong. My code is common in other answers but it seems to never send anything. I have tried in my own server and the company i'm working for server. I know this kind of answer has been answered many times before, but maybe i am missing something like others so this might be useful to someone besides me.

C# code:

```
       var buttonSaveClicked = new MouseEventHandler((o, a) =>
        {
            var user_token = this.textApiKey.Text;

            if (user_token.Length == 0) MessageBox.Show("API Key cannot be empty!", "API Key Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/networksWindows.php");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"user_token\": \"batatas\", \"bata\": \"cook\"}";

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
                User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(result);

                if (user.status == "error") MessageBox.Show("Invalid API Key. Please make sure you have generated a API key and insert it correctly.", "API Key Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
                else if (user.status == "success")
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));

                    t.Start();

                    this.Close();
                }
            }

        });
```

PHP script in my server:

```
<?php

$json = null;

if (isset($_POST['user_token']))
{
$json = $_POST['user_token'];

echo "user";
}

?>
```

Comment: `$_POST` doesn't parse JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `$_POST` to understand your data, it has to be sent as form-encoded `key=value&key2=value2`, not as JSON.

If you want to post JSON, you need to decode it on server side:

```php
$post = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if (isset($post['user_token'])) {
    // ...
}
```

You can replace `file_get_contents("php://input")` with [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), but its availability depends on configuration.

P.S. `streamWriter.Flush()` call is redundant.

Comment: Is this due to C#? Because i have used Java to send JSON and had the code i shown to receive the JSON post requests, and it worked fine.

Comment: You've probably used a different method to send data in Java, because it doesn't depend on language.

Comment: I see :) thank you for your answer. I will try to find a way to send in form-encoded using C#.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode your json post in PHP.
Try using this:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST);
if (isset($json['user_token']) {
  $userToken = $json['user_token'];
}
```

Comment: Your code will not work. 1. `json_decode` returns `stdClass`, not `array`. 2. `$_POST` does not contain raw post data.

Answer (score 0):

Decode your json as an array:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST, true);
```